# Are there any tools to monitor performance of Puma process queuing in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, puma

I'm trying to isolate puma process queuing as requests come into my application. I've adde middleware to determine the time between requests being received and responses sent back. Though, I'd like to see if, for whatever reason, Puma is taking a long time or workers aren't efficiently handling requests in the queue. I can't find any good tools to benchmark requests in development.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `rack-mini-profiler` gem to monitor time response. It will display result top left corner. And by default rails does what you want. You can check the response time on the bottom of every request.

```
Completed 200 OK in 2203ms (Views: 95.3ms | ActiveRecord: 71.5ms)
```

I strongly recommend you to use NewRelic for monitoring your application. Because it will handle very smoothly on both your system level and application level. It will monitor your database too.

Comment: Thanks. I use New Relic and rack-mini-profiler already, but they tell me the response time of the whole request-response cycle. I'm trying to isolate metrics of specific middleware and puma handling incoming requests and assigning processes.